# Image of the composition of a kernel with a cokernel.

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $ h:H\to G $ and $ k:K\to G $ be two normal monomorphisms and let $ f:H\ast K\to G $ theire coproduct.
It is always true that $ h\text {coker} k $ and $ f\text {coker} k $ has the same image?

Comment: Do you work in an arbitrary category with zero morphisms, or in the category of groups?

Comment: I'm interested in an arbitrary cathegory with zero morphisms, finite limits and colimits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Note that $\def\coker{\rm{coker}\,} \def\im{\rm{im}\,} \coker k=G\to G/(\im k)$ where $(\im k)$ is the normal subgroup generated by the image of $k$. Then, for a word $w=x_1y_1..x_ny_n$ with $x_i\in H,\ y_i\in K$, we have
$$w \overset{f\,\coker k}\mapsto [h(x_1)k(y_1)h(x_2)k(y_2)\dots]_{(\im k)}=[h(x_1)h(x_2)\dots]_{(\im k)} $$
because $k(y_i)\in (\im k)$ and these can be grouped on one side, using conjugations: if $z\in N$ for a normal subgroup $N$ and $x,y\in G$, then
$$xzy=xzx^{-1}xy\in Nxy\,.$$

Comment: You showed that the statement is true in groups category. This is true in any category with kernels and cokernels?